# How do I write find/write the script to restore a guest user in Lion (Mac OS X)?

Tags: script, osx-lion, guest-account

In Mac OS X 10.7, you cannot have a guest user if you encrypt the entire drive. An alternative is to create a psuedo-guest user. One of the downsides is that the feature where the guest user is restored to original state no longer exists.

**How do I write a script that restores the User Template found in `/System/Library/User Template/English.lproj`?**

I would also have to figure how to activate this script either at login or on logout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you *can* have a guest user on 10.7 on an encrypted drive. They're just limited to using Safari.